# Java ME record store problem

Tags: java, java-me, rms

I save data to Record store. If the aplication is running it works fine, but when I restart aplication data in record store is lost.

Here is my load command:

```
            try {
            int i=1;
            display.setCurrent(list2);
            RecordStore RS = RecordStore.openRecordStore("recordStore", true);
            RecordEnumeration re=  RS.enumerateRecords(null, null, true);
            adresaURL ad = new adresaURL();
            System.out.println("nacteno");
            while(re.hasNextElement()){
                byte br[] = RS.getRecord(i);
                ad.setPopis(new String(br));
                br = RS.getRecord(i+1);
                ad.setUrl(new String(br));
                System.out.println(ad.getPopis());
                System.out.println(ad.getUrl());
                i+=2;
                adresy.addElement(ad);
                list2.append(ad.getPopis(), null);
                System.out.println("nacteno2");          
            }
        recordStore.closeRecordStore();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Comment: And empty `catch` block is a terrible idea! You won't even be notified if you have a problem, you should **at least** put some logging or `e.printStackTrace()` there!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that won't work.

If you use a `RecordEnumeration` to iterate through your RMS (as you are), you must use `RecordEnumeration.nextRecord()` to retrieve the record data.  You are using `RecordStore.getRecord()`.

[`RecordEnumeration.nextRecord()`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/RecordEnumeration.html#nextRecord%28%29) advances your `RecordEnumeration` on by one.  As you never call it, your loop:

```
while (re.hasNextElement()) {
    ...
}
```

will never end!

Comment: ok I change it, but the problem is still there. It doesnt explain why loop doesnt start.nacteno2 isnt write on console

Comment: You didn't explain that was your problem!

Comment: Any exceptions being thrown?  Put a `System.out.println()` in your `catch` block.

Comment: no exceptions being thrown. when aplication is running the load and save command works fine but when i restat aplication loop in load command doesnt start. Propably record store havent any data.

Comment: Definitely record store hasn't any data.  How are you saving it?

Comment: byte1 = adU.getPopis().getBytes();                    recordStore.addRecord(byte1, 0, byte1.length);

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to add the code that you use to open and add data to the record store.